# PostgreSQL error from PHP script

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm new to the world of PostgreSQL, but I'm old hat at PHP and MySQL.

I have a PHP script that creates and (should) execute queries to a PostgreSQL DB. The connection is fine, I can get data back with no problem, but my INSERT statement keeps failing. Here's a sample of one of the queries created by the script: (all info is a matter of public record, so this is real data)

```
INSERT INTO
leads_lead ( EIN, NAME, ICO, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP, GROUP, SUBSECTION, AFFILIATION, CLASSIFICATION, RULING, DEDUCTIBILITY, FOUNDATION, ACTIVITY, ORGANIZATION, STATUS, TAX_PERIOD, ASSET_CD, INCOME_CD, FILING_REQ_CD, PF_FILING_REQ_CD, ACCT_PD, ASSET_AMT, INCOME_AMT, REVENUE_AMT, NTEE_CD, SORT_NAME)
VALUES ('010520599','BLUE KNIGHTS MOTORCYCLE CLUB','% DOUGLAS LAMPLUGH','216 HEATHER LN','FAIRHOPE','AL','36532-7105','0000','10','3','1000','201402','2','00','000000000','5','01','201412','0','0','02','0','12','0','0','0','Y42','AL II');
```

The error I get back states:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 1: ..._lead ( EIN, NAME, ICO, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP, GROUP, SUB...
```

This is returned in my console output, on a Ubuntu machine.

Any idea why this is failing? Trying to run this in the psql console give the same result, with a carat pointing at the 'G' in GROUP

I've also verified the spelling of the fields in my query matches the spelling (and case) of the fields in the database. I did NOT setup this database, but have full access to it.

Comment: GROUP is a keyword you have to escape it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose GROUP in double quotes to stop it being interpreted as a keyword

```
INSERT INTO
leads_lead ( EIN, NAME, ICO, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP, "GROUP", SUBSECTION, AFFILIATION, CLASSIFICATION, RULING, DEDUCTIBILITY, FOUNDATION, ACTIVITY, ORGANIZATION, STATUS, TAX_PERIOD, ASSET_CD, INCOME_CD, FILING_REQ_CD, PF_FILING_REQ_CD, ACCT_PD, ASSET_AMT, INCOME_AMT, REVENUE_AMT, NTEE_CD, SORT_NAME)
VALUES ('010520599','BLUE KNIGHTS MOTORCYCLE CLUB','% DOUGLAS LAMPLUGH','216 HEATHER LN','FAIRHOPE','AL','36532-7105','0000','10','3','1000','201402','2','00','000000000','5','01','201412','0','0','02','0','12','0','0','0','Y42','AL II');
```